# Complex number ( equation) Find the number of solutions of $z^3+\overline{z}=0$ ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Problem : Find the number of solutions of $z^3+\overline{z}=0$

Solution : $z^3 =-\overline{z} \Rightarrow |z|^3 = |(-\overline{z})|$

$\Rightarrow |z|^3 = |z| \Rightarrow |z|^3-|z| =0$

$\Rightarrow |z|(|z|^2-1)=0 \Rightarrow |z| =0 ; |z|^2=1 \Rightarrow |z| = \pm 1$

$|z|^2=1 \Rightarrow z.\overline{z} =1 \Rightarrow z.\overline{z} = 1$

Now the equation can be written as $z^3+\frac{1}{z}=0$ $\Rightarrow z^4+1 =0$ This equation has four roots. But answer is five roots. Please suggest

Comment: You forgot $z = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Daniel Fischer already commented:

From what you did in your calculation $$|z|(|z|^2-1)=0 \Rightarrow \color{orange}{|z| =0} ; |z|^2=1 \Rightarrow |z| = \pm 1$$ and from $|z|^2=1 \implies \ldots \implies z^4+1=0$ which gives $4$ roots plus $z=0$ gives one root.

Comment: For any $\;z\in\Bbb C\;,\;\;|z|\;$ is always non-negative, so no need in fact to put $\;|z|^2=1\implies |z|=\pm 1\;$ since *only* $\;|z|=1\;$ is possible. This can mislead.